# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Window Doesnt Appear

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, modal-window

I am trying to implement Modal Window in my html. On Clicking Register the modal Window appears. But when i implement a second modal window for Login only the background changed but the window doesnt appear

http://play.mink7.com/minkstock/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login modal div element is within the register modal div element. I think you forgot a closing `</div>`

Comment: I just did "Inspect Element" on Chrome and it showed up within the Registar modal div. :)

Comment: yeah.. looks like some error some where. thanks a lot. I tried to code format in aptana and it showed an extra div :(
Anyway it works :P

Comment: Nice catch @Calvin. Harsha, do a favor to yourself and do not use dreamviewer's design view for editing HTML Code, you can write whole site code either in code view or use netbean for same. it will help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add second modal for login modal, same as you have added for register-modal

```
<div id="login-modal" class="modal hide fade landing-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Login</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- your login code -->

   </div>

</div>
```